# Sending audit logs with rsyslog from CentOS to auditdistd on FreeBSD

Tags: logging, configuration, freebsd, rsyslog, audit

I am trying to send audit trails from rsyslog running on CentOS to auditdistd on FreeBSD using TLS.

auditdistd can be both sender and receiver. I would like to trick auditdistd into thinking that rsyslog is auditdistd running on a different machine.

The problem is that auditdistd requires the connecting clients to have a *certificate's public key fingerprint* generated with

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/security/auditdistd.cert.pem -noout -fingerprint -sha256 | \
    awk -F '[ =]' '{printf("%s=%s\n", $1, $3)}'
```

and a password. I cannot find any rsyslog documentation explaining how to provide a fingerprint and a password to the rsyslog sender.

Is it even possible? How can I achieve this?

---

### Related

- [Introduction to auditdistd and its configuration.](https://wiki.freebsd.org/auditdistd)